# Akka Streams only processing one Collection

Tags: scala, akka

I have the following situation, I have bunch of directories which have bunch of files. I'm processing them using AKKA but for some reasons only the last sequence is processed, Here is the code of the method I have, let me know if you see something wrong

```
def read(): Unit = {


    implicit val system = ActorSystem("LiveS3Parser")

    implicit val materializer = ActorMaterializer()

    val reader = new LiveSequenceFileReader(conf.getString("s3url"))

    val dateList = generateDates(conf.getString("startDate"), conf.getString("endDate"))
   reader.readAllFilesFromPath(conf.getString("s3url"))




    val seqElements = generateURLS(dateList, conf).via(readDataFromS3(reader)).via(parseJsonSeq())

    val sinkseq = Sink.fold(0)(persistDataSeq)
    val dataCounter = seqElements.toMat(sinkseq)(Keep.right)


    val sum: Future[Int] = dataCounter.run()

    sum.andThen({

      case _ =>
        sum.foreach(c => println(s"Total records Loaded: $c"))

    })

    Await.result(sum,Duration.Inf)
  }

def generateURLS(data: Seq[Long], conf: Config): Source[String, NotUsed] = {

    val s3URL = conf.getString("s3url")
    val dataWithURLs = data.map(x => s3URL.concat("dt=").concat(DateUtils.formatDate(new Date(x), "yyyy-MM-dd")))

    Source(dataWithURLs.to[scala.collection.immutable.Seq])
  }


  def readDataFromS3(lv: LiveSequenceFileReader)(implicit ec: ExecutionContext): Flow[String, Seq[KeyValue], NotUsed] = {

    Flow[String].mapAsyncUnordered(Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors())(url => Future(readFiles(url, lv)))

  }


  def parseJsonSeq()(implicit ec: ExecutionContext): Flow[Seq[KeyValue], Seq[Try[OptimizedSearchQueryEventMessage]], NotUsed] = {


    Flow[Seq[KeyValue]].mapAsyncUnordered(Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors())(line => Future(parseAllItems(line)))
  }


  def readFiles(url: String, lv: LiveSequenceFileReader): Seq[KeyValue] = {

    println("Reading Files from " + url)

    val files = lv.readAllFilesFromPath(url)
    println("Records to process" + files.size())
    files

  }






  def parseAllItems(seq: Seq[KeyValue]) = {
    seq.map(kv => parseItem(kv.getValue))
  }

  def parseItem(data: String): Try[OptimizedSearchQueryEventMessage] = {

    val retVal = Try(mapper.readValue(data, classOf[OptimizedSearchQueryEventMessage]))

    retVal

  }

def generateDates(startingDate: String, endDate: String): Seq[Long] = {

    val fmt = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd")

    val startDate = fmt.parse(startingDate).getTime

    val endingDate = fmt.parse(endDate).getTime


    val list = for (currentDate <- startDate to endingDate by TimeUnit.DAYS.toMillis(1)) yield currentDate


    list


  }
```

Comment: Could you please shorten your code example?  See the documentation on minimal, complete, & verifiable example: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I can shorten it but the relevant code will be lost. Folks will think that I'm trying to ask for code where as I'm trying to ask for help